# Printing workbook into multiple pdf's but exclude Sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel

All,

I have been able to achieve what I want. Except being able to exclude printing Sheet 1 when I pdf print the workbook. Any suggestion would help. I am still a noobie so if you see anything that may make this better please let me know.

```
    Sub ExportToPDFs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Select
    nm = ws.Name

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Procal Calibration Sheets\" & nm & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next ws

    YesNo = MsgBox("Open folder where the Calibration Sheets are saved?" _
    , vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Open Folder?")
    Select Case YesNo
    Case vbYes
    myval = Shell("explorer C:\Procal Calibration Sheets\" & FolderName, 1)
    Case vbNo
    End Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: Did you *really* edit your first worksheet's name to put a space between *Sheet* and *1* ?

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude with an IF your sheet

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then 'name of the sheet you want to exclude
        ws.Select
        nm = ws.Name

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\Procal Calibration Sheets\" & nm & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give it a shot and let you know my result.